# Accessing a Class Library through Web Service Reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, dll, reference

I have a C# class library which is consumed in a Web Service (dll is referenced). Further the web service is referenced in another ASP.Net project. All was working fine until I added a new Class in my Class Library project and updated all the references both in Web Service project and updated the Web Service reference in ASP.Net project. For some unknown reasons to me the newly added class in class library is NOT available in my ASP.Net project through Web Service reference while other old classes are available. When I try to access that newly added class in my web service code then its available there but also NOT found in WSDL description  of the web service in web browser .

Please help

Comment: Have you rebuild the class library ?

Comment: Yes. As I mentioned in the question that the newly added class is accessible in the Web Service project but NOT where the web service is added as a web reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason why the NEW type or Class is not exposed outside the web service. I was not using the NEW class in any way in my web service hence it was not exposed to outside world.As soon as I created a WebMethod with NEW class in class library as return type it became available everywhere. I didn't know this before so a good learning for me and may be for others as well.